# Why does my JavaScript regex not work?

Tags: javascript, regex, string

I don't understand why, but this code gives me a JavaScript error:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

String.prototype.format = function(values) {
    var result = this;
    for (var i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
        result = result.replace(new RegExp("{" + i + "}", "g"), values[i]);
    }
    return result;
};

alert("Hi {0}, I'm {1}. Are you, {0}?".format(["Chris", "swell"]));

</script>
```

### Error

> Exception thrown: invalid quantifier

What's wrong with it?

Comment: It's like `printf` for JavaScript! :P

Comment: Just as a side note, you could always use the `arguments` variable instead of passing an array as a parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you have to escape the `{` and `}`.

```
String.prototype.format = function(values) {
    var result = this;
    for (var i = 0, len = values.length; i < len; i++) {
        result = result.replace(new RegExp("\\{" + i + "\\}", "g"), values[i]);
    }
    return result;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The `{` and `}` have special meaning within a regex. They are used to specify exact quantifiers.

To treat them literally, just drop two backslashes before them like so: `\\{` and `\\}`.

One does not work, as I just found out. It must treat one of them as regex delimiters.